# Why is the first step always 73.73 kB while downloading from Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

My phone is a OnePlus 5T running Android 8.1. While downloading or updating apps from Google Play Store, the first step is always 73.73 kB.

I'm just curious. Is there any technical reason (e.g. file system) for that?

[image: google play store]

Comment: Interesting, I had noticed this before but never given it any thought. Just confirmed this on a Moto G5+ for both updates and new installs of apps, both on WiFi and mobile data. A Google search yielded no results... I am upvoting this question just because it has peeked my curiosity.

Comment: Speculation - you will find this file size for other OS like windows too (Google for 73.73 kB) so my guess is that is related to uninstall information. Place the files you need to uninstall first and then install.

Comment: @beeshyams Googling this is a little bit tricky. It returns similar number of results for 75.75 kB, 12.34 kB as well.

Comment: True. I'd noticed that too. But beyond that I have no idea

Comment: Downloading an app is not like a regular download where you click the link and it directly starts downloading. The download process consists of multiple HTTP requests before the actual download starts. May be those preliminary downloads are usually of the same size and add up to the shown 73.73 KB? And because the actual download request goes to a different server there is is a delay, used by the PlayStore app to update it's progress bar.

Answer (score -3):

The answer to the question depends on a few different variables, such as specific internet types, always come with high latency and low bandwidth, such as some satellite hookups, or dial up hookups if used.

If you do not have a stable internet connection, and your bandwidth is not consistent enough to be that bandwidth at all times, then perhaps your phone's wifi/data chip is only pulling that fast, or there could be background network applications running that are taking up all the bandwidth. If applications besides the one you are downloading something on are open, or apps have background processes using the network, that could be a cause of it.

The last option that i can think of is you could be getting throttled by your router, check your router for anything limiting, throttling, or prioritizing anyone's IP or mac addresses. Generally 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 192.168.1.1, 192.168.0.1, 192.168.1.0 or if you know you router is using another local ip address, login using that and sometime the default user is admin, with password of admin, password, or blank in most cases.

All else fails, it must be some sort of bug in your device, the apps, or some code between your device and the server.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily so. If it is happened with every single app, every single time, then it is something else going on than just bandwidth. Bandwidth would be way more variable than this.